# Display Web Page Title?

Tags: javascript, html, web, tags, mobile-website

Is there any way to display the title of the Webpage in pure text(HTML, Javascript)? I am making a mobile website that involves displaying a lot of text and It would be easier if I just had the website write the title on the toolbar on its own.

Comment: Clarification needed, what tool bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With javascript you can access it via `document.title`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ZvmWL/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but you may acces the title `Element` like any other `Element` in the `Document`:

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0] ;
```

There is also a shortcut to the title Node's text content ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title)) in the `Document` `Object`:

```
var text = document.title
```

The title `Element` is a required part of any HTML `Document` so replacing it -- if that is what you wanted to do -- is not legal ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2)).

Answer (score -2):

if you are using HTML then you would use `<title>`. I have an example for you down below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>What you want to name the webpage</title>
    </head>
</html>
```